# Can personal income information be provably shared in Estonia?

Tags: income-tax, income, estonia

Is it possible for an Estonian citizen to produce a government-signed document stating their income as it appears on their tax return? Maybe an electronically signed tax return transcript could be requested? I'd like to leverage Estonia's public key infrastructure to make a service that let's low-income Estonians prove their income to merchants online.

Comment: I think Estonia's PKI is for individuals, but you are looking for a solution for government entities to sign documents, not individuals.

Comment: I think cryptogrphic authentication is needed for a complete proof, and I'm pretty sure they use x509 certificates. The government is the root certificate authority so it should be able to sign documents.